# Unable to update Apexchart's category (x-axis label) dynamically in vue

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I am using Apexchart's bar chart and noticed that I am not able to change the x-axis's labels, ie the `categories`. Below is the component:

```
<template>
   <div>
     {{magnitudeByFreq}}
     {{chartOptions}}
     <apex-chart width="500" type="bar" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apex-chart>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    processedMouseData: null,
    gradientCountByType: null,
    magnitudeByFreq: null,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          id: 'vuechart-example'
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: []//['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative']
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'series-1',
        data: []
      }]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  watch: {
    gradientCountByType: function() {
      console.log(this.series.data)
      this.gradientCountByType ? this.series[0].data = this.gradientCountByType : console.log("Not working")
      this.gradientCountByType ?  this.chartOptions.xaxis.categories = ['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative'] : console.log("No xaxis")
    },
    magnitudeByFreq: function() {
      this.magnitudeByFreq ? this.series[0].data = Object.values(this.magnitudeByFreq) : console.log("ABX")
      this.magnitudeByFreq ? this.chartOptions.xaxis.categories = Object.keys(this.magnitudeByFreq) : console.log("ABA")
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Currently the `categories` is set to `[]`. This is because I want it to be filled by different data depending on which prop is using it. ie `gradientCountByType` or `magnitudeByFreq`.

The two lines below which are supposed to set the `category`:

```
this.gradientCountByType ?  this.chartOptions.xaxis.categories = ['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative'] : console.log("No xaxis")
this.magnitudeByFreq ? this.chartOptions.xaxis.categories = Object.keys(this.magnitudeByFreq) : console.log("ABA")
```

They don't seem to update the category at all. I should however mention that what gets displayed in the template `{{magnitudeByFreq}}` and `{{chartOptions}}`, do reflect there is a change in the `category` variable:

{{chartOptions}} shows:

```
{ "chart": { "id": "vuechart-example" }, "xaxis": { "categories": [ "Positive", "Neutral", "Negative" ], "convertedCatToNumeric": false } }
```

and

```
{ "chart": { "id": "vuechart-example" }, "xaxis": { "categories": [ "+0", "+100", "+1000", "+2000" ], "convertedCatToNumeric": false } }
```

Why is the `categories` attribute not displaying correctly? For whatever reason, the `categories` are showing numbers.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My guess is by changing the data attribute doesn't actually update the chart.

Instead we should create a reference to the chart:

```
<apex-chart ref="radar" type="radar" height="350" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apex-chart>
```

Then we can update the data with `updateSeries` method and update the chartOptions with `updateOptions` method:

```
this.$refs.radar.updateSeries([{
      name: 'Series 1',
      data: [your_new_data_here] //ie [1,2,3,4]
}])

this.$refs.radar.updateOptions({
      xaxis: {
        categories: [your_new_categories_here] //ie ["a","b","c","d"]
      }
})
```

Comment: great work!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<apex-chart ref="chart" :options="options" :series="series"/>
```

Chart component has **refresh** function. So we can re-render the chart.

```
this.series[0].data = [yourData];
this.options.xaxis.categories = [yourCategories]
this.$refs.chart.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

In vue 3 you should put chartOptions in reactive type so you can change it in whenever you want.

```
const chartOptions =ref({// your codes});
```

then in every methode or lifecycle

```
onMounted( () => {   chartOptions.value.xaxis.categories=myArrayValues;    }); }
```